# problem with QSqlTalbeModel . table is not showing

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtsql

i have a QsqlTableModel that is assigned to a table view .
my problem is that it doesn't populate the table inside the table view . it's still empty 
and it says (Unable to find table shots) - when printing lastError.text() - 
the function retrieveShotResults..(check code below)  is to test if there is a table called shots and yes it prints everything just fine , and the connection is fine also .. but the table view is still empty .
am i doing anything wrong ? 
please help 

thanks is advance

class SqlModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(SqlModel,self).__init__()


    self.connect()
    self.retrieveResult()

    self.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)

    self.setTable("""shots""")
    self.select()

def connect(self):
    # dataBase connection
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setDatabaseName("magenta")
    db.setUserName("admin")
    db.setPassword("moayyad")

def retrieveShotResult(self):
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("""select * from shots""")
    while query.next():
        table = query.value(1).toString()
        print table
```

Answer (score 0):

i found it ^_^ . the (connect) function should be called in the mainloop